# Best Practice for High Poly Model to interactive Flash

Tags: flash, maya

Our 3D designer has made some Maya models which look great because of their high poly count.  I'd like to create interactive versions of these models bound for our website leveraging Flash/Actionscript.  I'm not having problems accomplishing this basic task using small models.

However the complex models we've created are just too large for the web.  The process I originally pursued involved exporting the model to Collada and leveraging Papervision3D (or its ilk) to tie in with Flash.  The size of the Collada object is the limiting factor here.

Outside of creating multiple versions of each model - one for high resolution renderings and movies and another for flash interaction - does anyone have any best practices for leveraging these high-poly models in a dynamic interactive interface?  I'm open to ANY workflow and would like to avoid duplicating effort by creating multiple models.

This is my first attempt at diving into this, so I'm not trying to fake any expertise here.  I am, sorry to say, a noob.

Comment: In the newest incubator build of flash player (11) they've built in new GPU-powered 3d API which will let the graphics cards start doing some of the heavy lifting of 3D rendering.  Some Flash 3D engines, like http://away3d.com/ will allow for their use.  While not production ready yet, it might allow you to use the existing model without creating a low-res version.

Answer (score 0):

Swift3D by Electric Rain has a number of utilities that let you enhance or reduce polygon counts and thereby transform complex models into simplified Flash that are capable of running on the web. Papervision3D is one of many products that Electric Rain has.

Have you looked at the Swift3D plugins? http://www.erain.com/Products/Plug-ins/

Comment: I have not!  Geez, that might be easy.  I'll check that out and get with our designer to see if it will do the trick.  Thanks for the speedy response!

Comment: Hm.  The problem is that our developer is invested in Maya and not 3D Studio Max.  Perhaps their standalone product will do the same simplification.  I will look into that further.

Answer (score 0):

Maya's Vector renderer can save to swf:
http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/index.html?url=Rendering_Windows_and_Editors_Render_Settings_Maya_Vector_tab.htm,topicNumber=d0e609902

Answer (score 0):

You can use a displacement map of the high poly model for using it with the low poly model.

> Generate Displacement Map will output a displacement map from a subdivided object to its base mesh, or from one or more objects to another object. These displacement maps can then be used by an external renderer to recreate the details of the geometry they were generated from, and can be a great way to export high-poly detail such as displacement painting or mechanical details to a renderer or game engine. 
>   http://www.nevercenter.com/wiki/index.php?title=Generate_Displacement_Map